# Change behavior of Wordpress Tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a wordpress blog. When I click on a tag, it takes me to a new page with the headline of a relevant post. However, you have to click on the headline to see the actual post. I was hoping that if you click the tag in the tag cloud, it will show the headline and post/post pic immediately.

Is there a way to change the behavior of the tags?

Comment: Clicking a link to the tag (if I understand properly) takes you to the page with all posts using this tag.

Comment: You could modify your theme's `tag.php` template to achieve what you wish to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Wordpress default behavior: you're going to the tag archive page to select the post, because WP assumes - and rightly so - that you will have more than one post with any one particular tag. You need the tag archive page to select the post.

If you have only one tag per post, or one post with one tag, and will stay with that posting habit, than you can do what you want to do: see the full post per tag. Go to tag.php and change the_excerpt to the_content to see the whole post on tag.php rather than the excerpt.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt